# GPU theory - games vs video rendering

Tags: graphics-cards, video, 4k, rendering

I'm looking for a gaming computer that will render the sharpest 4K videos of outdoor scenes well, and I'm wondering how the reviews of how GPUs do with games relate to that. I've found the [Digital Storm Avon](https://www.digitalstorm.com/gaming-laptops.asp) (Best version), which looks very promising and reasonably priced, but all the reviews seem to be about using it to play games, while I want to render videos with it.

I've seen cautions in the reviews of GPUs, including some very similar to the Avon's NVIDIA RTX 2070 Max-P 8GB, saying that while they can put simple games into 4K with a pretty high frame rate, they slow down for more complex games. That raises a question, is the taxing part of the complex games generally the rendering, or is it something earlier in the process, like generating the situation itself that then gets rendered, which is not part of videos?

To put it in a nutshell:

1. Is the Avon good enough to render minimally compressed 4K videos of the outdoors with maybe 60 fps;
2. Is it possible to get it delivered in less than a week;
3. If not, can you recommend something else, first good enough and second preferably less than $3K, and;
4. As a cherry on top, is there some straightforward breakdown of processing games, which I could compare to rendering videos?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HW Recs! In general, we can give you a better answer if you **specify an upper price limit**, and **desired specs** if you have the capability to do so. Otherwise listing a few more examples of your intended use scenario can help us narrow down the specs you might need.

Comment: I rewrote the question - does the person who downvoted it still think it's bad?